# What (a User's local) time is it?

Tags: feature-request

Many people give wide disclosure in the "location" field of their info
page, many more don't.

While I'm not too interested in knowing the precise location of a user, on the contrary it happens that I'd like to know if, for a user I'm interacting with, it's bedtime, office hours, you know. So I go to the user's info and I see that s/he has no "location"...

**[Q]** At the moment, is it possible to get this info [the user's local time] from SE?

If it is impossible with the current info available to SO, why not improve the info that SO has about a user? immediate possibilities that spring to my mind

1. providing a field for the time zone, or
2. enhancing the request for a location with an option to choose which info is shown on a visit, e.g.,

   ```
   location: _________________________________
             [x] Show location and local time
             [ ] Show only local time
   ```

but I don't exclude other ones.

Comment: **This seems to be about the user, not the question,** and is therefore potentially against the spirit of the site: to assemble a library of good questions and answers by concentrating on the question, not the poster.  Besides, it is 0430 here in the USA now.  What does that tell you? That I work at night? Or do I get up early?  You do not know when I might be available or unavailable, unless the site thoroughly tracks me.  While I think SO collects the needed info, I would prefer that information about my activity here not be assembled in such a way.

Comment: Many people don't want to disclose their location information for various reasons. Showing their local time would be akin to giving away this information as it at least allows others to pinpoint a geographical region. And as Paul says, this isn't relevant for questions and answers anyways.

Comment: It shouldn't matter what time it is at the users location.  The main driver of this seems to be "Is the user around to respond to my comments or answer".  And you can already make a more reasonable guess at this than guessing based on their timezone.... look at the last seen time on their profile.  Doesn't tell you definitely that they are still around, but it at least gives you an idea that they were on the site recently.

Comment: @psubsee2003 I think that if you formulate this as an answer, I'm going to accept it. Thank you for the enlightment, ciao

Comment: @Paul «This seems to be about the user, not the question, and is therefore potentially against the spirit of the site» and then you give good reasons why the additional info is possibly useless. I agree that local time info is not always useful. About my motivation, I thought that knowing the local time would help me in sorting (sort of, re your remark on _your_ local time) my priorities but, as you stated at the top of your comment, maybe I focus too much on helping the user and less than I should on the Answer. I have to think about it. Thanks.

Comment: @l4mpi Yes, definitely yes but I don't propose to enforce the time zone, I propose to give the user a further choice: display nothing, display only the time zone, display in full her/his location. I, for one, in my "location" have just the time zone. If this is offered explicitly as an option, maybe someone would choose the _intermediate solution_. About pinpointing a geographical region... in my case you can choose from Cape North, Norway to Cape of Good Faith, ZA, oh well,  Alaska has a tz of its own (hasn't it?)... but again, the user decides what to show. Thank you for your comment, ciao

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Reading between the lines, it would appear that the main purpose of this feature request is not to actually know the user's time zone but to actually know if they are likely able to respond to you if you leave comments.

If that interpretation is correct, then knowing the time zone is really just going to lead you to make false assumptions.

- Maybe the user actually doesn't visit the site during the work day
- Maybe the user is an insomniac
- The user doesn't actually program for a living, so only visits during the nights and weekends
- Maybe the user is traveling and didn't bother to change the user setting to indicate they are in a different timezone

I'm sure I could come up with a lot more, but I think I made my point.  A time zone field is worthless to use as a gauge on if someone is likely to respond immediately simply because not everyone visits the site in neat little buckets defined by a clock.

The system already provides a better indicator of if the user is still around right in their profile

> [image]

If the time is recent, it is more likely they are around, if not, then they might not.

Even then it still won't tell you when they will come back.  Maybe they will be back in 5 minutes, 30 minutes, 5 hours, a week and half, or never.

Don't try to help someone just because you don't think they will be back to respond immediately.  If you have an answer, leave it.  If you have a comment asking for more info, then post it.  The user will eventually see it and either respond or not.

Comment: I feel particularly pinned down by "the user is an insomniac", and I have to say this particular misbehavior of mine got worse and worse after I dicovered SO. Ciao

Comment: _"If you have an answer, leave it. If you have a comment asking for more info, then post it."_ yes, of course, but there are times when I feel like I need to set priorities! or go detox? who knows... ;-)